# JPQL QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token -- Jhipster

Tags: hql, jhipster, jpql

I have a problem with the code generated by Jhipster.
In my repository, i have this query

```
@Query("SELECT member FROM Member member left join fetch member.categories where member.id =:id")
    Optional<Member> findOneWithEagerRelationships(@Param("id") Long id);
```

when i run my application i have this error :

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   unexpected token: member near line 1, column 8 [SELECT member FROM
>   com.cf.usercfmanagement.domain.Member member left join fetch
>   member.categories where member.id =:id]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find this on the JPQL documentation, but I'm suppose that `member` is a **reserved word** (like `order`, `group`, etc), because [there is](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL) the `MEMBER OF` clause on JPQL.

So, use another alias for `Member` entity. Per example:

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM Member m left join fetch m.categories where m.id = :id")
Optional<Member> findOneWithEagerRelationships(@Param("id") Long id);
```